# Lenient string comparison React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm building a quiz, and I'd like to compare a given user's answers to a list of possible correct answers. So far, when checking the given user's score by comparing their answers to the correct ones, I use the `===` operator, which obviously checks for an exact match.

Is there any way to do a less strict String comparison in React? For example, if `StringA` contains 75% of characters in `StringB`, the comparison can return true?

I haven't seen this online so I'm quite sceptical.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want "fuzzy" comparison. Check out [fuzzyset.js](https://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js/). It looks like it might do what you need (and more). Their "usage" example looks like it would get you a similarity score that you could use to make the determination:

```
a = FuzzySet(['Michael Axiak']);
a.get("micael asiak");
[[0.8461538461538461, 'Michael Axiak']]
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I import this? I've included `<script src="fuzzyset.js"></script>` in my html file, but I get an error that `FuzzySet is not defined`

Comment: @Adam Have you downloaded the `fuzzyset.js` script and put it in your project? It's available in their GitHub: https://github.com/Glench/fuzzyset.js